# Is this restriction open or closed?

Tags: general-topology

Let $A=\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} | x \ge 0\} \cup \{ (x,0) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \} $ and let $p : A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $p(x,y) = x$ be the restriction of the projection to the first coordinate.

Determine whether p is a quotient map, an open map or a closed map?

I have been able to successfully show that $p$ is a quotient map. However, I am currently stuck in proving the open or closed part. I know the definition of open and closed map,I just need an idea of a proof or a disproof. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't $\{ (x,0) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \} \subset \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} | x \ge 0\}$?

Answer (score 0):

For openness consider the the subset $\Big\{(x,y)\in A \mid y > 1\Big\}$ which is open. Is its projection open?

For closedness consider the subset $\Big\{\Big(x,\dfrac{1}{x}\Big)\mid x>0\Big\}$ which is closed. Is its projection closed?

Comment: In both cases, the images are neither open nor closed. However is the openness and closedness of both initial sets trivial/obvious? I can't seem to see this as obvious.

Comment: Even if it is not obvious to you you can try to work that out for your satisfaction. For first set note that complement is closed. For second one, I don't really know what will be the easiest way to show the set is closed but to see it, can you think of a limit point that's not be in the set?

Comment: The second is just like the real line that extends to infinity on both sides. It's just curved as compared to real line.